# How do I print the next common element in a string?

Tags: c, string

I wrote a program that finds a common letter in a string, I intend to print that letter, and the letter that is the second most common, how do I achieve that?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

 #define MAX 10
 #define MAX_FREQ 256
int main()
{
    char string[MAX] = {0};

    int i = 0; 
    int freq[MAX_FREQ] = {0};

    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(string, MAX, stdin);
    if(string[strlen(string)-1] == '\n') {string[strlen(string)-1] = 0;}

    for(i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        freq[string[i]]++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_FREQ; i++)
    {
        if(freq[i])
        {
            printf("Most common: %c, 2nd most common: %c\n", i, i-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code for this question about [Swap two most frequent characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664603/) — a question which actually has a totally different title, but the objective is closely related to this (it goes further, swapping all occurrences of the most common with the second most common letter, and all occurrences of the second most common with the most common letter, but that's trivia).  The code to find the maximum and second maximum is very similar to [Xzenon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491551/xzenon)'s.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comments in the code will be enough for you to understand.

```
// max - most common, snd - second most common
int max_freq = 0, snd_freq = 0;
char max_char, snd_char;

// iterate through frequency array
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FREQ; i++)
{
    if (freq[i] > max_freq)
    {
        /*
         * we had a previous max_freq that satisfied max_freq > snd_freq
         * since we found a new freq > max_freq, we'll change snd_freq as well
         * to max_freq
         * order: freq[i] > max_freq > snd_freq
        */

        snd_freq = max_freq;
        max_freq = i; //it'll be converted, don't worry

        snd_char = max_char;
        max_char = str[i];
    }
    else if (freq[i] > snd_freq)
    {
        snd_freq = freq[i];
        snd_char = i;
    }
}

// print most and second most common characters
printf("%c %c", max_char, snd_char);
```

Answer (score 0):

use code like below one:-

```
int max = INT_MIN , max2 = INT_MIN,maxi,max2i; //using <limits.h>   
for(i = 0; i < MAX_FREQ; i++)
{

    if(max<=freq[i])
    {
        max = freq[i];
        maxi =i;
    }

    if(freq[i]<=max && freq[i]=>Max && max1i! =i)
    {max2 = freq[i];
      max2i = i;
     }
}
```

now you can easily use max1i and max2i index to print those characters

Comment: I don't think you read the question correctly, he wants the characters, not the number of occurrences.

Comment: he can use max 1 or max2 to get those character easily.. i just told how to get those max values

Comment: First of all, you added those AFTER I posted my comment. Second, your solution has flaws. Example: freq['a']=5,freq['b']=2;freq['c']=6 will give you a max = 6 and max2 = 2 (not 5).

Comment: Well it's not mentioned in the question just replace smaller with smaller than equal to

Comment: I have edited for understanding of people who read the main idea is logic of finding those two max